SpringBoot 3 An incompatible version of the Apache Tomcat Native library
I have an application using springboot 3 (3.3.4) which is being developed in Windows 11 with thymleaf and bootstrap 5 using intellij.  The application compiles and runs under windows with no errors.  When I compile the application in Ubuntu (24) the log shows an error:
An incompatible version [1.2.31] of the Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version [1.2.34]
Although it renders the home page ok.  It could be a red herring, the the application has a login page which when completed causes and error to be generated (the page it calls is /error?continue) there is no errors generated in the log though in fact the output of the page is:

timestamp   "2024-10-13T19:59:31.883+00:00"
status  999
error   "None"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I've ensured that the java versions are the same under windows and ubuntu.  Removed the error.html page, but without any error logs it's difficult to know where to go.

It isn't an error it is a warning. Apparently you included or have installed the native library which can offer some performance benefits. It is in compatible so it won't be used so you loose some of those benefits.

Solved the problem by changing from open jdk to oracle jdk
